# OnTriggerEnter not working at Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to detect a ball entering throw a ring in a basketball game. I am using the following script at the ring

```
public class Anotar : MonoBehaviour {

    private ControlJuego control;

    void Start(){
        GameObject gameControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag ("ControlJuego");
        if (gameControllerObject != null)
        {
            control = gameControllerObject.GetComponent <ControlJuego>();
        }
        if (control == null)
        {
            Debug.Log ("Cannot find 'GameController' script");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collision col)
    {
        control.puntuar (2);
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
    {
        //control.puntuar (3);
    }
}
```

The ring has a box collider set as trigger to detect the OnTriggerEnter method. It also has a mesh collider to detect when the ball touch it throw OnCollisionEnter. My problem is that OnTriggerEnter is not working (used breakpoint inside and it doesn't stop). Actually OnCollisionEnter works fine. My ball has a sphere collider and both use rigidbody. Any idea?

Edit: I attach screenshots from my ball and ring
[image]

[image]

Comment: OnTriggerEnter works when isTrigger property of box collider set to true

Comment: yes, it is set to true at the ring box collider, but it does't work

Comment: rigid body have attached?

Comment: yes, in both ring and ball

Comment: can you post screenshots of the editor?

Comment: do *not* use mesh colliders.  they are never used, except in very unusual situations.  for a basketball hoop or the net, you just use a normal collider that is roughly the same shape.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collision col)
{
    control.puntuar (2);
}
```

this will never work. OnTriggerEnter needs a Collider not an Collision.
Try this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col)
{
    control.puntuar (2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the problem

Answer (score 4):

You should add kinematic rigidbody to the basket ball. A static trigger can detect rigidbodies but it doesn't detect moving colliders, even if the trigger has a rigidbody.

Comment: Thank @carbine I need the ball to move and using kinematic property it stay static. I need to do something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4TC7H6trLo

Comment: So instead of making the ball as kinematic, can you try setting it for the hoop and see if that solves it.

Comment: The hop have the kinematic property as true yet. I'm getting crazy with it :S

Comment: Why do you need 2 colliders? Mesh as well as box for the Torus? Can you try with only one? They have different behaviour and might interfere with each other?

Comment: If I uncheck the mesh collider the ball does not behave correctly when it touch the ring. Anyway I've tried to delete one and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have been through the same problem, I was trying to shoot an enemy with an arrow, but the arrow OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider) was not called at beginning, I enabled is Trigger in the enemy (the body I am trying to call the method on) this finally fixed my problem.